# Free Alternative to Matlab for Biomedical Engineer

Tags: windows, gratis, programming, 3d

Matlab is necessary for biomedical engineers. But it's not free. Is there any free software like Matlab which is good at Signal and Image Processing, Numerical and Statistical Methods, Optimization, Modeling in biology(3D). Can anyone suggest the best freeware software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is the combination of [python](http://python.org) *programming langage*, [ipython](http://ipython.org/)/[jupyter](https://jupyter.org/), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), [scipy](http://scipy.org/) and the numerous graphing, plotting & IDE options.

There are numerous books & academic publications dealing with the use of python in the biomedical field.

All of the above are downloadable for free gratis, are open source and are cross platform working well on Windows/OS-X/Linux, etc.

There are a number of bundles of the above software that have been put together notably [Continuum Analytics Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/) *base install free*, [Python X-Y](https://python-xy.github.io/) *free* and [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) *free for users at degree granting institutions but decidedly not otherwise*

Comment: are these Softwares  enough  for medical 3D Imaging?

Comment: Yes, and there are several research projects that use them.

Comment: Anaconda is in my opinion the best Python distribution for technical users.

Comment: @EricShain - I have added Anaconda above.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to python & related libraries, I would also recommend to look at

- octave, a free analogue of matlab. Unfortunately I have never used that myself (neither matlab) so I cannot comment
- R, the statistical language.  My impression is that most of the stuff that is done in matlab can very well also be done in R.  R has a ton of various libraries, here is a list related to medical imaging: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MedicalImaging.html
- there is also a promising "startup language" julia but I doubt it is in any way mature enough for a serious project.  But you may check it out for simple simulations or other stuff, it is implemented in a very nice way and it's speed is approaching that of C and fortran.